# Should I include books I used for independent study in personal statement?

Tags: graduate-admissions, application

I am trying to write me Personal Statement for applied mathematics graduate admission in the US. I did an *independent study course* when I was a senior. The topics were about mathematical foundations of image processing and reading papers. This is definitely something that I would like to mention in my personal statement.

But I am not sure how detailed it should be. For example, should I just say: "we read two papers", or should I go deeper and say: "the first papers use variational calculus to develop an active contour model for detecting edge"?
Should I mention some of the specific books my professor assigned to me, or do I just say: "I read about functional analysis"?

Comment: If the statement has a limited word count, write up by the word count. If you have enough room to go into details, go for it. Also, is your independent study ground-breaking and unique, or is it fairly bog-standard and will not stand out of the crowd of applications?

Comment: @G-E What could I say? My whole life and person do not stand out ╮(╯_╰)╭ Otherwise I would be chilling on some island right now

Comment: I'll take your word. I was not judgemental, just asking questions to help with your reaching an answer to your own question.

Comment: @G-E I was just kidding. It was a two-quarter independent study, mostly reading books, going through derivations and writing Matlab. There was no original research going on. I did that mostly because I would like to see what applied math is like (outside the classroom)

Comment: Would you agree my first comment as a good answer to your question then? ;)

Comment: From personal experience, I'd think these are important information you should add (especially if you have nothing more interesting to say!)

Comment: If this is so central to your personal statement, perhaps you should approach the whole thing a different way: First figure out who the researchers you might want to work under/with are, then talk to them about applying, and have them advise you on what to focus your personal statement on.